# Inserting a document with Pymongo - InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to insert a document (twitter information in this case) into Mongo database with PyMongo.

As you can see below, tweets_listdt[0] is exactly the same as

```
{
     'created_at': u'Sun Aug 03 17:07:24 +0000 2014',
     'id': 2704548373,
     'name': u'NoSQL',
     'text': u'RT @BigdataITJobs: Data Scientist \u2013 Machine learning, Python, Pandas, Statistics @adam_rab in London, United Kingdom http://t.co/pIIJVPCuN8\u2026'
}
```

But I couldn't save tweets_listdt[0] into my Mongodb while I could do so with the later one.

```
In[529]: tweets_listdt[0] == {'created_at': u'Sun Aug 03 17:07:24 +0000 2014',
 'id': 2704548373,
 'name': u'NoSQL',
 'text': u'RT @BigdataITJobs: Data Scientist \u2013 Machine learning, Python, Pandas, Statistics @adam_rab in London, United Kingdom http://t.co/pIIJVPCuN8\u2026'}
Out[528]: **True**
```

This one fails:

```
In[530]: tweetsdb.save(tweets_listdt[0])
tweetsdb.save({'created_at': u'Sun Aug 03 17:07:24 +0000 2014',
 'id': 2704548373,
 'name': u'NoSQL',
 'text': u'RT @BigdataITJobs: Data Scientist \u2013 Machine learning, Python, Pandas, Statistics @adam_rab in London, United Kingdom http://t.co/pIIJVPCuN8\u2026'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-529-b1b81c04d5ad>", line 1, in <module>
    tweetsdb.save(tweets_listdt[0])
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1903, in save
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 430, in _insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.codec_options, sock_info)
InvalidDocument: **Cannot encode object: 2704548373**
```

This one works okay:

```
In[531]: tweetsdb.save({'created_at': u'Sun Aug 03 17:07:24 +0000 2014',
 'id': 2704548373,
 'name': u'NoSQL',
 'text': u'RT @BigdataITJobs: Data Scientist \u2013 Machine learning, Python, Pandas, Statistics @adam_rab in London, United Kingdom http://t.co/pIIJVPCuN8\u2026'})
Out[530]: **ObjectId('554b38d5c3d89c09688b1149')**
```

#### Update on 5/10

Thanks Bernie. The PyMongo version I'm using is 3.0.1.

here is the check of id's data type:

```
In[36]:type(tweets_listdt[0]['id'])
Out[37]:long
```

If I just use:

```
for tweet in tweets_listdt:
    tweetsdb.save(tweet)
```

The error mentioned above would happen.

But if I add in this line, everything is okay:

```
tweet['id'] = int(tweet['id'])
```

And when I directly assign

```
tweets_listdtw = {'created_at': u'Sun Aug 03 17:07:24 +0000 2014',
 'id': 2704548373,
 'name': u'NoSQL',
 'text': u'RT @BigdataITJobs: Data Scientist'}
```

**tweetsdb.save(tweets_listdtw)** is working, and

```
print type(tweets_listdtw['id'])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

Got confused again... So definitely long type is okay...But why after I change 'id' into int, the saving is working?

Comment: What is the datatype of `id` ? Can you show us how are you assigning value to `id`?

Comment: Thanks, thegreenogre. I read the whole dictionary from twitter api, and  'id': 2704548373 is one of the items in the dictionary. Everything was okay and an ObjectID was generated when I directly saved the dictionary to the database. Because there were a lot of such dictionaries,  I combined all dicts into a list named tweets_listdt so that I could use for loop to save those dictionaries into the database.  Then this problem occured.

Comment: If you're not using a native type in your document (string, integer, date, boolean, etc) you need to make sure it's encoded correctly. Try a type-conversion on the value of `id (tweets_listdt[0]['id']=int(tweets_listdt[0]['id']))`.

Comment: Great! The problem is solved. The data type of id was long, which is not accepted. Thanks very much!

Comment: This comment is confusing to me. long is definitely a supported data type in PyMongo. The error message is coming from PyMongo's C extensions. I just tested with your example document and it saves fine for me, with and without the C extensions. Are you sure the datatype of 'id' is long? What version of PyMongo are you using?

Comment: Thanks, Bernie. I update my post a little. I got confused again...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is that `numpy.int64` is foreign to MongoDB. I have had the same problem.

The solution is to convert the offending values to a datatype that MongoDB will understand, here is an example how I converted those offending values in my code:

```
try:
    collection.insert(r)
except pymongo.errors.InvalidDocument:
    # Python 2.7.10 on Windows and Pymongo are not forgiving
    # If you have foreign data types you have to convert them
    n = {}
    for k, v in r.items():
        if isinstance(k, unicode):
            for i in ['utf-8', 'iso-8859-1']:
                try:
                    k = k.encode(i)
                except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
                    continue
        if isinstance(v, np.int64):
            self.info("k is %s , v is %s" % (k, v))
            v = int(v)
            self.info("V is %s" % v)
        if isinstance(v, unicode):
            for i in ['utf-8', 'iso-8859-1']:
                try:
                    v = v.encode(i)
                except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
                    continue

        n[k] = v

    collection.insert(n)
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 11):

1. If you have numpy object for ex. int or float in the json/dict **data_dict** which you want to send over mongo using pymongo.
2. one might get **"cannot encode object"** error, to resolve this I have used a custom encoder like this.

---

```
class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, numpy.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, numpy.floating):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, numpy.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return super(CustomEncoder, self).default(obj)
        
data_dict_1 = json.dumps(data_dict,cls=CustomEncoder)
data_dict_final  = json.loads(data_dict_1)
```

- Please check out docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html
- this way does not matter how your Json data is organised, it works.

Comment: A very elegant solution

Answer (score 6):

I'm a big fan of Oz's answer.  To expand on it with python 3 :

```
def correct_encoding(dictionary):
    """Correct the encoding of python dictionaries so they can be encoded to mongodb
    inputs
    -------
    dictionary : dictionary instance to add as document
    output
    -------
    new : new dictionary with (hopefully) corrected encodings"""

    new = {}
    for key1, val1 in dictionary.items():
        # Nested dictionaries
        if isinstance(val1, dict):
            val1 = correct_encoding(val1)

        if isinstance(val1, np.bool_):
            val1 = bool(val1)

        if isinstance(val1, np.int64):
            val1 = int(val1)

        if isinstance(val1, np.float64):
            val1 = float(val1)

        new[key1] = val1

    return new
```

It has recursion for those nested documents, and I think python 3 stores all strings as unicode, so I removed the encoding parts.

Comment: python set seems to be a problem to.
Added a new if and converted them to a list:
```if isinstance(val, set):
            val = list(val)
```

Comment: ```def correct_encoding(self, obj): if isinstance(obj, np.bool_): return bool(obj) if isinstance(obj, np.int64): return int(obj) if isinstance(obj, np.float64): return float(obj) if type(obj) is dict: # Nested dictionaries return {key1: self.correct_encoding(val1) for key1, val1 in obj.items()} elif type(obj) is list: return [self.correct_encoding(_) for _ in obj] return obj``` refactored to include list as well

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use silly solution but it works.. supposed `x` is `numpy.int32` or `numpy.int64` type variables.. this `int(str(x))` simple casting just working fine with PyMongo

Comment: ha! it worked. To help clarify, this error comes up when a value from a key value pair is a number in a numpy format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert a class object in mongodb, you need to convert it into dictionary representation. You can not insert the direct object.

```
{"key": class_object__dict__}
```